# Gradle Build Failure: Could not open cp_init remapped class cache

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite, buildship

Whenever i try to open Spring Tool Suite 4 i keep getting this error

Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for 6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66 (C:\Users\itzde.gradle\caches\5.6.4\scripts-remapped\eclipsePlugin_19ol36i63qs7425dr89rkxtsu\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\cp_initb88fbed980d87867994e661e74c75e1f).
Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'D:\Spring Tools\SpringToolsWork.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle' (C:\Users\itzde.gradle\caches\5.6.4\scripts\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\cp_init\cp_initb88fbed980d87867994e661e74c75e1f).
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

Comment: This might be an incompatibility between the used Gradle version and the JDK you are using to run the IDE, most likely the Gradle version not up-to-date enough to run on that JDK. I would recommend to upgrade the Gradle version used by the project and retry.

Comment: If that doesn't help, I would try to reach out to the buildship project and file an issue with them and ask for advice: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinLippert , I had similar issue and your suggestion (that it was incompatibility between Gradle and jdk) was my issues.